# printf shows end of line character

Tags: printf

I have a
char pointer that points to a string: "123 \\n."
if I do a printf ("%s", char_pointer)
I see 123 \n. instead of 
123
.
What would be the easiest way to get rid of the extra \ so that it displays properly assuming I have can't change the formatting of the original string?

This is an example of the string I am handling

```
const char *source = \
" printf (\"This is a test %d %d \\n.\",4,3);                                       \n";
```

Comment: Show us where you assign the value `"123\n"` to `char_pointer`.

Answer (score 0):

you have two slashes there.  That means that in `\\n` the first `\` escapes the second `\`, and it is printed as-is.  The following `n` is interpreted as a standalone character instead of part of `\n`.

If you want the `\` to be printed at the end of the line, you need an additional `\` there.